# Technical terms for user-website interaction

Tags: word-choice, technical, diagramming, tech-writing

I am making a context diagram of a website and I noticed that the words I used for a user and the website's interaction are not consistent or cohesive.

I have been using the pairs of words below to indicate that a user requests to "see" a webpage:

[image]

> a user "visits" a website and the webpage "views" (as a response to the user)

I can't find a more acceptable alternative for these two but I am sure there are better ones out there that I just don't know.

One more, what should I use if the page that a user wants to see is a popup or specifically a [modal element](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) (which means a user is not directed away from their current page)?

Comment: A user that visits a website _requests_ content, and the website (the server actually) _serves_ the content that is requested. Content can be a page, or data on a page, or a file to download, or anything else.

Comment: @oerkelens, thank you, that's better! But how about if a "page" is a popup or modal? Is request/server still applicable?

Comment: Whatever data is served, is served. Whether that is visually formatted data (a webpage, a form, a pop-up) or raw data (web-page content data, an application file), it is still data that is served to the user.

Comment: The site pops or popups a window or dialog- if the user requested it, the user requested content and the page served it in a popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user **views** and **inputs**.  A website **displays** and **outputs**.  A modal pop-up is called a [modal window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window).

Comment: Yes. Another way of looking at the "two-way" interaction is that the user *requests* information, and the website *delivers* it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Exactly.  Would use those two terms if talking about the network stack or some form of mode/language (http).  When I see user and website though I usually stick to something more basic.

Answer (score 3):

"Request" and "response" are the nouns typically used in HTTP specifications and libraries. "Request" and "respond" are the corresponding verbs.

Answer (score 1):

For a pop-up window you could say the user **invokes** it, then after interacting with it **dismisses** it.

Answer (score -1):

My *Microsoft Manual of Style* says to use "pop-up window".  The reference was not specific to webpages, but the context was similar to what you describe.

Here's some of the entry from page 359

*Do not use as a noun.  Also do not use as a verb to mean open or appear.

'Pop-up window' is all right to use in references to windows that pop up in context-sensitive Help.  Do not use 'pop-up window' as a synonym for dialog box.*

Comment: It's not really a verb, is it? You are suggesting the user "pop-up" window the website, and then the website "pop-up window" the user? Since the OP asks for words to put at the arrows :)

Comment: The second part of the question had not yet been answered.  The comments about serving a page were excellent responses that needed nothing more.  ;)  I should have been more clear and complete.  Microsoft is very clear that that is exactly what you should not do.